# What would be your interpertation of this requested queue implementation?

Tags: java

I had been reading two books on JAVA and while covering data structures, I started to do some online research with regards to "QUEUE" implementation. I have an extensive background in FLEX, however ACTIONSCRIPT isn't comparable to advance languages.

Lets say if I was on a job interview and asked to implement a Queue of Object, how should I pursue it as? I am not looking for code help here, I would like to what would you quick answer be? I have been to Java online docs and do understand there are 13 known implementing classes, and "LinkedList" is one of them.

Google search has return more results with "LinkedList" implementation code than any other.

My apologies if you find this question to be rubbish or pointless in anyway.

[Oracle's Java online doc ref:](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html)

Comment: Are you asking what the Queue ADT is?

Comment: What exactly are you asking? A `Queue` is a generic interface in Java, representing the general concept of an ordered queue of things that need to be processed; a "todo list" of sorts. There's a zillion different implementations, depending on requirements. (The short answer to an interview question would be: "It depends". A more practical interview question would be: "Here are the requirements, what type of queue would you use?"). In the docs you linked, browse through the list of "all implementing classes" for a taste.

Comment: Yes, queues can also be array based, however such practice is discouraged if possible. So I wanted to know what how others would pursue given the requirements that "a simple queue of Objects". Would you based this requested queue as an "array based"? Or would you pursue a "Linkedlist based". I have made very clear that a "Verbal Question" can be asked to hear what the answer be. Yes,indeed so, there quite a few possibility for this implementation. I have gone over those classes, and each class extends a special purpose.

Comment: @Combustion007 Array-based queues are discouraged? That's news to me. Why do you say that? (And hint: if you maintain an index for both ends, you don't have to resize on each pop/push.)

Comment: @yshavit, can you provide me a link that demonstrates this (maintain an index for bot ends), please. Thank you

Comment: Index for both ends: Websearch "ring buffer".

Comment: @Combustion007 Adding to keshlam's "ring buffer" keyword, many implementations of a [deque](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue#Implementations) can be indexed from both sides in constant (ring buffer, series of arrays) or linear (doubly linked-list) time. Also, the idea that "array based queues are discouraged" is misguided and incorrect; depending on usage and requirements an array-based queue is perfect (ring buffer FIFO, multiple array deques, etc.).

Comment: @Combustion007 And to be more concrete, [ArrayDeque](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayDeque.java#ArrayDeque.addFirst%28java.lang.Object%29) in the JDK is such an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know what the concept of a queue is and how it differs from a stack (closely related data structure)? If so, you should be able to think of multiple ways to implement it.

Which is best depends on the exact requirements of the task it's being used to address.

So the right response to that interview question is not to start coding but to ask them for more information about the requirements your implementation has to address. Performance? Memory size? Multitasking? Any limits on maximum queue depth, eg to guard against things like a DOS attack? What's being enqueued -- objects, primitives, other? Specific kinds thereof? Parameterized type? Are there any values which should be discarded (maybe null shouldn't be enqueued)?

Knowing the requirements, you should be able to judge which answer is appropriate. Starting coding without asking the requirements is immediately going to earn you a demerit.